Python Proxy Server with TLS Failing: SSLContext Error with PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER
I have written a Python-based proxy server that supports both HTTP and HTTPS. The goal is to redirect or block specific domains, for example, redirecting certain malicious websites to a secure page (like Google). I want to deploy the proxy in a secure environment using TLS.
Current Behavior
Error Message:
SSL error occurred: Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context (_ssl.c:806). Closing connection gracefully.
   If the SSL handshake fails, please make sure the self-signed certificate is properly installed in the client as a trusted authority.

The proxy correctly forwards HTTP connections and works without encryption.
However, when connecting over HTTPS (port 443), the SSL handshake fails, resulting in this error.
Minimal Reproducible Example
Here is my Python code:
import http.server
import socketserver
import requests
import socket
import select
import ssl
import urllib3
from urllib.parse import urlparse, quote

# Suppress InsecureRequestWarning warnings
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# List of blocked domains
BLOCKED_DOMAINS = [
    "example.com",
    "blocked.com",
    "malicious-site.com"
]

# Certificate files for SSL connections
CERT_FILE = "cert.pem"
KEY_FILE = "key.pem"

class ProxyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_CONNECT(self):
        target_host, target_port = self.path.split(":")
        target_port = int(target_port)

        # Check if the domain should be blocked
        if any(blocked_domain in target_host for blocked_domain in BLOCKED_DOMAINS):
            print(f"CONNECT request to blocked domain: {target_host}. Redirecting to Google.")
            target_host = "www.google.com"
            target_port = 443

        try:
            # Establish connection to the target
            context = None
            if target_port == 443:
                # SSL context for secure connection with custom certificate
                context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
                context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
                context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3
                context.check_hostname = False  # Disable to avoid hostname verification
                context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE  # Disabled for local testing
                context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT_FILE, keyfile=KEY_FILE)

                # Specify secure cipher suites
                context.set_ciphers('ECDHE+AESGCM:ECDHE+CHACHA20:ECDHE+SHA256:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES')          
            raw_sock = socket.create_connection((target_host, target_port))
            if context:
                # `server_hostname` must be set for `check_hostname` to work
                conn = context.wrap_socket(raw_sock, server_hostname=target_host)
            else:
                conn = raw_sock

            # Connection established successfully, send response to client
            self.send_response(200, "Connection established")
            self.end_headers()

            # Data transfer between client and target server
            client_socket = self.connection
            sockets = [client_socket, conn]

            while True:
                readable, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], sockets, 10)
                if not readable:
                    break
                for sock in readable:
                    other = conn if sock is client_socket else client_socket
                    data = sock.recv(4096)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    other.sendall(data)
        except ssl.SSLError as ssl_error:
            print(f"SSL error occurred: {ssl_error}. Closing connection gracefully. If the SSL handshake fails, please make sure the self-signed certificate is properly installed in the client as a trusted authority.")
        except (ConnectionAbortedError, socket.error) as e:
            print(f"Connection error during data transfer: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to establish connection: {e}")
            if not self.wfile.closed:
                try:
                    self.send_error(502, "Failed to establish connection")
                except BrokenPipeError:
                    print("Broken pipe when attempting to send error response.")
        finally:
            try:
                if 'conn' in locals() and conn:
                    conn.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error while closing connection: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 8080
    with socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(('', port), ProxyHandler) as httpd:
        httpd.allow_reuse_address = True
        print(f"Proxy server running on port {port} with HTTPS support")
        httpd.serve_forever()


Possible Questions
Am I using the wrong SSL context (ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER) in the context of a proxy? Should I use a different context instead?
Could the issue be due to using a self-signed certificate? If so, how can I ensure the client accepts the certificate as trustworthy?
Are additional configuration steps in the SSL context necessary to achieve a successful SSL handshake?
Does the SSL context need to be configured differently because the proxy acts both on the server and client sides?
I've been trying to solve this problem all day, but I'm stuck. This project is very important to me because I want to create something that protects both children and adults from pornography. If anyone is willing to help, I would be really grateful! I'm determined to find a solution and appreciate any support.

PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER should be used for the server side of TLS. But since you are creating a connection to another server you act as a TLS client in this case - hence you must use PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT

Apart from that it makes no sense for me what you are doing: a CONNECT request should only pass through the data, not make a TLS handshake by its own. load_cert_chain makes no sense if you are a TLS client but don't have to use client certificates. ... I have the feeling that you need to fundamentally rework what you are doing after you got a better understanding of the problem and how HTTP proxies work.
